# Order of Ip's returned for API Based service discovery to AWS Cloud Map

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, service-discovery, aws-cloudmap

We are currently doing a service discovery from our java application using "API Based service discovery to AWS Cloud Map". We are using the "DiscoverInstances" call. As we have multiple containers with the same properties, the call returns multiple IPs and we always select the first one in the list. Is there any algorithm behind the order of IPs in which the AWS CloudMap responds?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - it's a random "multivalue routing"